# What files/data Can a User Gain Access to From your Xcode Project - Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, csv, core-data

I recently learned that it's a bad idea to store data you want secure in a plist, and it's better to store it in a keychain, since a user can get access to what is stored there.

This makes me ask what other data can a "motivated" user get access to from inside your Xcode project, once it is in the App store. For example, can someone download the core database of a project just by downloading the app? Or if you have a .csv file in your project folder which you use to parse data from, could a user download the original .csv file just by having access to the app?

This may be an obvious answer like "of course not, the user can't get any files from your project." But I'm fairly new, and I couldn't find any discussion about this, so I wanted to make sure that I am going about things in a secure way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps on iOS are "bundles", which just means they're a directory with a name that ends up in `.app`. Any file that you include for your app to use ends up in the bundle, and a motivated user should be assumed to have access to everything in the bundle. This includes any data models, CSV files, images, sounds, etc, that you include as well as compiled storyboards and so on. Decompiling code is challenging but reverse-engineering data models is easy.

Here's how you can have a look:

1. Compile your app.
2. In Xcode, go to the file browser on the left. Under "Products", find your app.
3. Right-click on the app entry and select "show in Finder".
4. In Finder, right-click the app and select "show package contents".

Now browse the bundle contents and see what's there.

This isn't the same thing as *saving* data, it's what comes built in to your app. Saved data is also mostly available. Keychain data should be unavailable because Apple encrypts it and keeps it separate from the app.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear answer. Is this enough of a concern to not include pre-loaded information and to try an alternative method? I'm concerned about piracy issues with pre-loading data onto the app if it can be accessed without making the requisite in-app purchases. 

The app I'm working on is meant to run offline, which is why I took this approach. But it sounds like this may be a bad idea?

Comment: Getting things like preloaded data isn't going to help someone make pirated copies of your app. Your app needs to verify in-app purchase by more than checking whether files exist. Even if the downloads are there, does your in-app purchase code say they *should* be there?

Comment: The app is a flash card app, and I was originally going to have all the data in a pre-loaded database, and updates done through csv files included in the project folder. If the user made an in-app purchase, it would unlock a certain number of flash cards from the database that they could use. So it's not about copies of the app, but people actually just downloading all the flashcard content immediately without even needing a purchase.

Comment: I noticed that what is in Assets.xcassets isn't directly included in the "show package contents." I see something called Assets.car. I'm assuming this means that whatever is included in Assets.xcassets is included in this .car file and the user can also get access to them?

Comment: Yes, that's the asset catalog. Please though, I've seen excessive worry over piracy be the death of otherwise useful apps. It's easy to let this concern run away with you so much that you end up with a crippled or nonexistent app. Invulnerable to piracy, maybe, but only by being useless or missing.

Comment: Thank you. You bring up a very good point and probably something I need to keep in mind as I go forward. I appreciate this feedback.

Answer (score 1):

A "motivated" user has access to everything that ends up in your app bundle when Xcode packages the app for upload. Look at the "Copy Bundle Resources" Build Phase of your project to get an idea which files are copied in addition to your compiled code.